# Unnable to delete data in realtime firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to delete all of the data inside of specific node, without knowledge of specific id's. I've written some function within button click:

```
        val dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Message")
    dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (data in snapshot.children) {
                data.ref.removeValue()
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })
```

Whenever I'll click the button, the app crash after a couple of seconds, with this stack trace:

```
   2023-10-24 15:08:55.651 15854-15878 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.myapplication            E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2023-10-24 15:08:58.479   571-1625  TaskPersister           system_server                        E  File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2023-10-24 15:09:24.970 15854-15881 RunLoop                 com.example.myapplication            E  Firebase Database encountered an OutOfMemoryError. You may need to reduce the amount of data you are syncing to the client (e.g. by using queries or syncing a deeper path). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data
                                                                                                    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 16 byte allocation with 692344 free bytes and 676KB until OOM, target footprint 201326592, growth limit 201326592; giving up on allocation because <1% of heap free after GC.
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:1252)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.WriteTree$1.evaluate(WriteTree.java:238)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.WriteTree$1.evaluate(WriteTree.java:234)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.WriteTree.layerTree(WriteTree.java:433)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.WriteTree.calcCompleteEventCache(WriteTree.java:243)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.calcCompleteEventCache(SyncTree.java:999)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.setValue(Repo.java:467)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference$1.run(DatabaseReference.java:290)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
2023-10-24 15:09:26.347 15854-15881 RunLoop                 com.example.myapplication            E  Firebase Database encountered an OutOfMemoryError. You may need to reduce the amount of data you are syncing to the client (e.g. by using queries or syncing a deeper path). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data
                                                                                                    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 426856 byte allocation with 163360 free bytes and 159KB until OOM, target footprint 201326592, growth limit 201326592
                                                                                                        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3553)
                                                                                                        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3522)
                                                                                                        at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:244)
                                                                                                        at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:251)
                                                                                                        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:461)
                                                                                                        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:474)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.drainTo(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1280)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.drainTo(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1263)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.drainQueue(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:862)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1425)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:876)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform$1.handleException(AndroidPlatform.java:106)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$1.afterExecute(DefaultRunLoop.java:89)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
2023-10-24 15:09:26.349 15854-15882 AndroidRuntime          com.example.myapplication            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: TubeSockReader-1
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 15854
                                                                                                    java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@a687cc3[Not completed] rejected from com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$1@522e072[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 463677, completed tasks = 11460]
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2082)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:842)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:345)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:712)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock.onError(WebsocketConnection.java:106)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket.runReader(WebSocket.java:432)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket.access$000(WebSocket.java:47)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket$2.run(WebSocket.java:143)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
2023-10-24 15:09:26.349 15854-15854 AndroidRuntime          com.example.myapplication            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 15854
                                                                                                    java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@43fb527[Not completed] rejected from com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$1@522e072[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 463677, completed tasks = 11460]
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2082)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:842)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:345)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:712)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.DefaultRunLoop.scheduleNow(DefaultRunLoop.java:105)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.scheduleNow(Repo.java:304)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(DatabaseReference.java:286)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(DatabaseReference.java:159)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.removeValue(DatabaseReference.java:437)
                                                                                                        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$onClick$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.kt:52)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (15854) for package com.example.myapplication ----------------------------
2023-10-24 15:09:26.396 30365-30388 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.currencyexchange         E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2023-10-24 15:09:26.417   419-419   BpTransact...edListener surfaceflinger                       E  Failed to transact (-32)
2023-10-24 15:09:29.899   571-1625  TaskPersister           system_server                        E  File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2023-10-24 15:10:29.373   571-767   ClipboardService        system_server                        E  Denying clipboard access to com.android.chrome, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
2023-10-24 15:10:29.378   571-768   ClipboardService        system_server                        E  Denying clipboard access to com.android.chrome, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
2023-10-24 15:11:24.686   571-767   ClipboardService        system_server                        E  Denying clipboard access to com.android.chrome, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
2023-10-24 15:11:24.688   571-768   ClipboardService        system_server                        E  Denying clipboard access to com.android.chrome, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
2023-10-24 15:11:28.275   571-767   ClipboardService        system_server                        E  Denying clipboard access to com.android.chrome, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
2023-10-24 15:11:28.401   571-767   ClipboardService        system_server                        E  Denying clipboard access to com.android.chrome, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
2023-10-24 15:11:52.889  5250-10954 WakeLock                com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2023-10-24 15:11:57.631 16102-16102 gle.android.tts         pid-16102                            E  Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2023-10-24 15:11:58.051 16149-16149 equicksearchbox         pid-16149                            E  Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2023-10-24 15:11:58.629  5250-5345  bwfc                    com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  Phenotype API error. Event # edax@b9088f2a, EventCode: 5 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
                                                                                                    bwdx: 29501: Stale snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.search.googleapp.device#com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox(change count changed - expected 10  but was 9)
                                                                                                        at bwfg.b(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):16)
                                                                                                        at bwff.g(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):0)
                                                                                                        at bwfc.e(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):4)
                                                                                                        at bwfc.f(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):2)
                                                                                                        at avsy.eo(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):1)
                                                                                                        at avtf.run(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):14)
                                                                                                        at dfhf.run(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):2)
                                                                                                        at aced.c(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):6)
                                                                                                        at aced.run(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):8)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
                                                                                                        at acjn.run(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):0)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
2023-10-24 15:11:58.636 16102-16145 tflite                  pid-16102                            E  third_party/tensorflow/lite/core/subgraph.cc:903 tensor.data.raw != nullptr was not true.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.247  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.247  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.248  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.248  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.249  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.253  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.254  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.255  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.255  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.256  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.256  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.256  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_en-US is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.256  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.257  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.275  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.275  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.276  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.277  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.277  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.278  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.278  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.279  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.279  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.280  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.281  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.282  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_en-US is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.283  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.283  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.338  5250-12348 NanoAppLogging          com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  Failed to begin contexthub communication
2023-10-24 15:11:59.578  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_en-US is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.582  1559-2100  SP.Service.AiAi         com.google.android.as                E  captions_i18n_v0_mandatory is opened by other clients. It will stay open until all clients close it.
2023-10-24 15:11:59.763  5376-5455  MDD                     com.google.android.gms               E  FileGroupManager: Trying to add expired group enpromo-state-config.
2023-10-24 15:12:00.053  5376-25996 Pay                     com.google.android.gms               E  [Migration operation] Active tapandpay account not found! [CONTEXT service_id=198 ]
```

When I've wanted to add new value to the database, I've implemented something wrong, so I have a multiple keys with same value, instead of just one. Now, I just want to "wipe" this node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the following error:

> Firebase Database encountered an OutOfMemoryError. You may need to reduce the amount of data you are syncing to the client (e.g. by using queries or syncing a deeper path).

Because your `Message` node that you're trying to read, contains much more data that can fit into your memory, hence the error.

Besides that, there is no need to read a node in order to delete it. You can simply call [DatabaseReference#removeValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#removeValue()) directly on the desired node:

```
val dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Message")
dbref.removeValue().addOnCompleteListener { 
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        Log.d(TAG, "The node is successfully deleted.")
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed with: ${it.exception?.message}") //
    }
}
```

When you perform asynchrony operations, never ignore potential errors.

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

```
val dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Message")
dbref.removeValue()
```